# Are the SQL, Postgres OIDs are dyanamic or static

Tags: postgresql, oid

I'm new to Postgres OIDs.
I want to know, wre the SQL, Postgres OIDs are dynamic or static?
Means after creating OIDs is there any possibility to change them automatically or manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL OID is static, but it will not survive dumping and restoring the database, so you should NOT rely on it.

Actually, in PostgreSQL 8.1 and later, configuration parameter [default_with_oids](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-DEFAULT-WITH-OIDS) is `false` by default, which means that unless you use `CREATE TABLE` using [`WITH OIDS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) option, OIDs will NOT be present in your table.

So, long story short - OIDs are thing of the past. Do not use it, do not rely on it, forget about it.

Comment: "Do not use it, do not rely on it, forget about it." +1